# Projection map $\pi:\left(\mathcal{O}/n\mathcal{O}\right)^\times \to\left(\mathcal{O}/\gcd(n,m)\mathcal{O}\right)^{\times}$ of a CM elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-theory

In this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00208-009-0373-1) the author has mentioned in page $693$ under section $2.2$ that for an Elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with CM by an order $\mathcal{O}$ of an imaginary quadratic field $K$ there is a positive integer $m$ with the property, that for each positive integer $n$, we have

$$\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[n])/K)\cong\pi^{-1}(\operatorname{Gal}(K(E[\gcd(n,m)])/K),$$ where $\pi:\left(\mathcal{O}/n\mathcal{O}\right)^\times\to\left(\mathcal{O}/\gcd(n,m)\mathcal{O}\right)^\times$ is the canonical projection. (Note: If $R$ is a ring, then $R^{\times}$ is the group of units of $R$.)

What is this canonical projection map? How does it look exactly?

If somebody could give me the explicit description of this projection map or point to me a source where this map is well described, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: The ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}/n\mathcal{O}$ to $\mathcal{O}/d\mathcal{O}$ for any divisor $d$ of $n$ is the map given by the ideal $(d)$, I think that is obvious. Is this your question or how these rings are equal to the Galois groups in the line above?

Comment: $x + n\mathcal{O}\mapsto x + d\mathcal{O}$ whose kernel is $(d) = d\mathcal{O}/n\mathcal{O}$. I doubt this is a research level question, I am sorry.